# Visual Studio - Is it possible to link from Test Project to the object files of Code Project?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, testing, linker-errors

[figure: my current Solution Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90L6s.png) (the language is chinese)

I added reference in TestProject to CodeProject, but seems I can only link to "square" function in mymath.c when CodeProject generates a static lib.

Usually, how would you set up a test project in order to link to the CodeProject? when CodeProject is to a console project (which generates exe, not a static lib). Or would you just add mymath.c as the source of TestProject?

Is there any prefered way? thanks.

[my CodeProject is written in C, and **TestProject**(following code) would be using gtest in C++]

```
#include "stdafx.h"

extern "C" {
#include "mymath.h"
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", square(6) );   // <-------
    return 0;
}
```

which generates **unresolved external symbol error** of "square"

Comment: You can link to a static library. You can not link to an executable.

Comment: I meant linking to the objects of CodeProject, so that I can test them.

Comment: Why don't you just drag & drop the files in to TestProject. It can be done without making duplicates of the *.cpp files.

Comment: Is that the same as "add existing item" ? yes, this is a way, but it would be really convenient if I could just use the existing compiled objects of CodeProject, no need to drag a lot of other sources because of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can link your major project's **.obj** files as `additional dependencies` to your test project.

`properties`->`VC++ Directories`->`lib directory`: add your projects **obj's path** here

`properties`->`linker`->`input`->`additional dependencies`: add your **obj's file name**